# Kylin build fails at first step

Tags: kylin

My Kylin metadata is corrupt, so I removed all metadata and reinstalled Kylin on the same server.

I tried running:

```
$KYLIN_HOME/bin/sample.sh
```

And it is not giving any error.

So i tried to create a simple cube with 1 fact and 2 dimension tables.

But my cube build failed at its first step, with this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kylin.source.hive.CreateFlatHiveTableStep.getCubeSpecificConfig(CreateFlatHiveTableStep.java:100)
    at org.apache.kylin.source.hive.CreateFlatHiveTableStep.doWork(CreateFlatHiveTableStep.java:105)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:113)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.DefaultChainedExecutable.doWork(DefaultChainedExecutable.java:57)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:113)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.impl.threadpool.DefaultScheduler$JobRunner.run(DefaultScheduler.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: anybody had experienced this problem please share me some solution....

Comment: Purge metadata and start over again usually works. Try drop hbase table 'kylin_metadata'.

Comment: @user6608138 do you install kylin on hortonworks/cloudera or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem，and fixed。
The reason is that zookeeper already have directory kylin。When I remove then kylin  on zookeeper，cube build successfully
1. use zkCli.sh to connect to zookeeper
2. rmr /kylin
3. restart kylin。

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.This is helping me a lot.